# Batch Data Entry: Got error from sandbox to production

Tags: batch, deployment, error, change-set, production

I have some errors on the Change Set deployment to production. I installed the batch data entry package on sandbox and now, I got the an error related to

> In field: field - no CustomField named
>   CCI_Transition_Support__c.Batch__c found

I don't know if I need to uninstal the batch data entry on sandbox and instal it on production after data migration.

Someone know the solution for it?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you verified that the field is indeed included in your change set or already exists in production?

Comment: Hi Make. Yes, all needed fields was mapped on change set. I installed batchdataentry on production and the change set to production worked properly. Thanks!